# Make Timer start counting as soon as ViewDidLoad is called

Tags: swift, timer, viewdidload

I have set Timer in ViewDidLoad in this way:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
           timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(handleAnimation),
       userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But until it fires out the first handleAnimation method I need to wait for 3 seconds.
Is there a way to make timer fire out the function as soon as the viewDidLoad function is executed?

Comment: you should declare your timer as a property of your view controller otherwise you wont be able to invalidate it.

Comment: When I try to declare it as a property of the VC I receive this error in the compiler : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue handleAnimation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: `var timer = Timer()` and in your viewDidLoad `timer = .scheduledTimer(...`

Comment: thanks, if I invalidate it , it works fine but if I fire it again It doesn't work

Comment: "Stops the timer from ever firing again and requests its removal from its run loop" In other words after invalidating a timer if you need to fire it again you would need to reschedule it.
"

Comment: Thank you, that's what I did and It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell the timer fo [`fire`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1414035-fire) immediately.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
       timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(handleAnimation),
   userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
timer.fire()
```